# xml text to matrix of tags

Tags: python, xml, nlp

I would like to make a matrix or list of labels from an xml file.

For example, given this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Words about John.  
 <person Key="NameHash:001">John Master-Smith</person> is a coder.
<person Key="NameHash:002">Aleksandra</person> likes goldfish.
She likes to dance.
```

I can retrieve the text via python:

```
with open('test.txt.xml') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()
```

which returns:

```
Words about John.
 John Master-Smith is a coder.
Aleksandra likes goldfish.
She likes to dance.
```

after which I split into tokens:

```
[['Words', 'about', 'John']
['John', 'Master-Smith', 'is', 'a', 'coder']
['Aleksandra', 'likes', 'goldfish']
['She', 'likes', 'to', 'dance']]
```

What I would like to do is map these tokens to an array which indicates whether or not the token is in a tag.

i.e.  I would like to return:

```
[[None, None, None]
['NameHash:001', 'NameHash:001', None, None, None]
['NameHash:002', None, None]
[None, None, None, None]]
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

---

I have tried this, but the unfortunate part is, I would like for there to be an ability to know if the text from the original xml actually exists within a tag, not just seeing if some user given string exists within the tags from the xml.

```
with open('test.txt.xml') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()
    tag_text = [x.string for x in soup.find_all('person')]
    # split into word tokens with specific tokenizer
    sentences = tokenize(text)
    tag_mask_all_sentences = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        print(sentence)
        sentence_mask = []
        for word in sentence:
            found = False
            for s in tag_text:
                if word in s:
                    sentence_mask.append(1)
                    found = True
            if found==False:
                sentence_mask.append(None)
        tag_mask_all_sentences.append(sentence_mask)

    for tag_mask in tag_mask_all_sentences:
        print(tag_mask)
```

Which returns:

```
['Words', 'about', 'John']
['John', 'Master-Smith', 'is', 'a', 'coder']
['Aleksandra', 'likes', 'goldfish']
['She', 'likes', 'to', 'dance']

[None, None, 1]
[1, 1, None, 1, 1, None]
[1, None, None]
[None, None, None, None]
```

You can see that this is not quite right, as the first sentence's 'John' is not in a tag.  I'm really not sure what happened with 'is' and 'a'... I think it's because it found that those characters existed within the tag text - which is obviously very wrong.

Ultimately an easier way to think of the output I need is something like this - where `w` is a word and `0` is for padding, `.` is for non-tagged and `T` is for tagged.
[image]

Comment: How does your "array" look like? (There are no arrays in Python, unless you use NumPy.)

Comment: A list of lists is fine.  After this step I will likely move it to a 2d numpy array;  however, the most important function here is to get some way to know if the text from `soup.get_text()` at any point within the string is within a tag or not as given from `soup.find('person')`.

Comment: But what's in the list? Please include an example in your question.

Comment: @DYZ I added an example.  The basic idea is to get the text from an xml (via `soup.get_text()` and tokenize, and then assign to each token whether or not it exists within an xml tag.